# Where are the Windows Driver Kit files installed?

Tags: windows, driver

I've installed the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) but can't find the source files anywhere. The install directory is given as Program Files (x86)\windows Kits\8.0, but I can't find anything there. Where are these installed to?

I'm specifically looking for the sample files described [in this article about simulating proximity features](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731#content).

Comment: In the old days the WDK would install to `c:\winddk`, did you check there?

Comment: No dice. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty heavy changes in this version of the WDK.  The sample code is no longer included, it is now a [separate download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e).  The proximity sample pops up from [this query](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/site/search?query=proximity&f%5b1%5d.Value=proximity&f%5b1%5d.Type=SearchText&f%5b0%5d.Value=Official%20Windows%20Driver%20Kit%20Sample&f%5b0%5d.Type=User&ac=4)

Comment: Finally they did it. Originally there wasn't an option to download the entire package, just to browse online...

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for the **non-sample** files, they do get installed by default to:  `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0`

Note the x86

Comment: Note that the subfolder depends on your OS. For Windows 8 (August 2012) --> `8.0`. Windows 8.1 (October 2013)--> `8.1`.  Windows 10 (July 2015) --> `10`. Windows 11 (October 2021) --> `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows 10, the samples are published through Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples